# SonarQube Scanner fail on on-premise TFS when FXCop rules are activated

Tags: tfs, sonarqube, continuous-integration

when I run sonar task in CI pipeline it fails with message

```
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No FxCop analysis has been performed on this project, whereas it contains cs files: Verify that you are using the latest version of the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild, and if you do, please report a bug. In the short term, you can disable all FxCop rules from your quality profile to get rid of this error.
at org.sonar.plugins.fxcop.FxCopConfiguration.checkMandatoryProperties(FxCopConfiguration.java:104)
at org.sonar.plugins.fxcop.FxCopConfiguration.checkProperties(FxCopConfiguration.java:95)
at org.sonar.plugins.fxcop.FxCopSensor.execute(FxCopSensor.java:69)
at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.SensorWrapper.analyse(SensorWrapper.java:53)
at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:88)
at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:82)
at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:68)
at org.sonar.scanner.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:88)
at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:180)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:288)
at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:283)
at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:281)
at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:261)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:48)
at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:84)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:121)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecuteTask(Batch.java:116)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:111)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:63)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:233)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.runAnalysis(Main.java:123)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:77)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
```

When I deactivate all FXCop rule on Sonar server it works OK. When I activate FXCop rules and use sonarqube scanner task version 3.0.2 it works.

What I have wrong?

TFS 2017 Update 3 On premise

Build agent 2.122.1

SonarQube Scanner 3.1.0 or 3.0.2

SonarQube Server 6.7

Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47750986/analysis-failing-with-error-no-fxcop-analysis-has-been-performed-on-this-projec/47794551#47794551

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Analysis failing with error "No FxCop analysis has been performed on this project, whereas it contains cs files"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47750986/analysis-failing-with-error-no-fxcop-analysis-has-been-performed-on-this-projec)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using version 1.2 of the fxcop plugin found here. https://github.com/DanielHWe/sonar-fxcop/releases That version of the plugin gets rid of the error, however in my testing I am getting zero fxcop rule violations reported to sonarqube. I am currently testing with TFS 2018 and SonarQube 6.7.